# Docker container is restarting, and I cannot stop the cycle

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I created a docker container using the following docker compose file listed on the docker hub page...

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  redmine:
    image: redmine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:3000
    environment:
      REDMINE_DB_MYSQL: db
      REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD: example
      REDMINE_SECRET_KEY_BASE: supersecretkey

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_DATABASE: redmine
```

Now it is continually crashing and restarting, and I can not figure out how to kill it permanently!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `restart: always` setting from your `docker-compose` file (`restart:no` is the default value) and use `docker-compose up -d` again you might see your container be stopped instead of crashing.

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  redmine:
    image: redmine
    ports:
      - 8080:3000
    environment:
      REDMINE_DB_MYSQL: db
      REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD: example
      REDMINE_SECRET_KEY_BASE: supersecretkey

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_DATABASE: redmine
```

> `restart: always` always restart the container if it stops. If it is manually stopped, it is restarted only when Docker daemon restarts or the container itself is manually restarted.

more information you can refer [restart-policy](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-restart-policy)

if you want to stop all containers from docker-compose we can use `docker-compose down`

Comment: I ran the command you provided (docker-compose up -d) and received the error "no configuration file provided: not found"

Comment: @Scorb You need to switch your file path which container your docker-compose file then use that command

Comment: Still autorestarting. Can you at least tell me how to stop the auto restart. I don't want to deploy the container again, i just want to stop it in any way possible.

Comment: @Scorb use `docker-compose down`

Comment: That does not work. It just says "no configuration file provided: not found"

Comment: I have the same problem as @Scrob